# Handling data value restrictions in dl query

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, dlquery, owl-api

I am trying to run a DL Query using the OWL API, using the DL Query Example(http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/code/ci/aef6981535f07a2d0d44c394b9f4d5415f36025a/tree/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java)

hasExperience some (Experience and hasYearsOfExperience some int[>=1])

This runs fine and displays the expected result in Protege, but returns the following error in Java:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Prefix not registered for prefix name: :
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.DefaultPrefixManager.getIRI(DefaultPrefixManager.java:199)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.getIRI(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:3112)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.getOWLDatatype(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:563)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseDataRangePrimary(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:1032)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseDataUnionOf(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:1013)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseDataIntersectionOf(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:995)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseDataRange(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:988)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseDataRestriction(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:908)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseNonNaryClassExpression(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:787)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseUnion(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:688)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseIntersection(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:663)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseNestedClassExpression(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:1212)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseObjectRestriction(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:819)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseNonNaryClassExpression(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:783)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseUnion(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:688)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseIntersection(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:663)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseNestedClassExpression(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:1212)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseObjectRestriction(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:819)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseNonNaryClassExpression(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:783)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseUnion(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:688)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseIntersection(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:663)
    at org.coode.owlapi.manchesterowlsyntax.ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.parseClassExpression(ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser.java:650)
    at org.coode.owlapi.examples.DLQueryParser.parseClassExpression(DLQueryManager.java:413)
    at org.coode.owlapi.examples.DLQueryEngine.getInstances(DLQueryManager.java:324)
    at org.coode.owlapi.examples.DLQueryManager.getInstances(DLQueryManager.java:127)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come from the way you handle prefixes and not from the DL query.

Make sure your default prefix is present: You can look in the top of your .owl file where prefix mappings a declared.

In your code you should have something like that too:

```
String base = "http://example.com/";
PrefixManager pm = new DefaultPrefixManager(base);
```

You could also look at the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/code/ci/aef6981535f07a2d0d44c394b9f4d5415f36025a/tree/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) in order to know more about prefixes.

Comment: The issue was a due to type mismatch. An OWL literal is an Integer, whereas I was querying for an int. I fixed the problem by replacing int[>=1] with xsd:integer[>=1].